# Prove that $s_n\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the sequence $(s_n)_{n\geq 1}$ given by $s_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}$. Prove that  $s_n\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{k(k-1)}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\quad \forall k\ge2$$
and telescope.

Answer (score 0):

We proceed by induction on $n \in \mathbb N$.

**Base Case:** For $n = 1$, we have $s_1 = \frac{1}{1^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{1}$, which works.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that the inequality holds for $n' = n - 1$, where $n \geq 2$.

It remains to prove that the inequality holds for $n' = n$. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
s_n
&= s_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&\leq \left(2 - \frac{1}{n - 1} \right) + \frac{1}{n^2} &\text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&= 2 + \frac{-n^2 + n - 1}{n^2(n - 1)} \\
&\leq 2 + \frac{-n^2 + n}{n^2(n - 1)} &\text{since } -1 \leq 0\\
&= 2 + \frac{-n(n - 1)}{n^2(n - 1)} \\
&= 2 - \frac{1}{n} \\
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score -2):

Look at the Riemann zeta function.

$\zeta(2)=\pi^2 / 6$ which is smaller than $1.7$.

Since every value of your function is smaller than $\zeta(2)$ your claim follows.

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values

Comment: "every value of your function is smaller than $\zeta(2)$": not true for $n \le 2$. This bug can easily be fixed, but then you have to prove that $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$...

Comment: Yeah telescoping is better.
But I was not fast enough to see it and post first.

Comment: This answer is completely off-topic, it doesn't answer anything while the OP was expecting an induction proof or a at least a proof, not a quote from a wikipedia page